# Express middleware infinite loop

Tags: node.js, azure, express, iis

Express middleware runs into an infinite loop for encoded URLs,
I have french letters in my URL, so every time I try to hit something a URL like `/équipement`

The express server runs into an infinite loop trying to process the URL(`/%C3%A9quipement/`) and I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

This doesn't happen on my local environment, happens on the dev environment hosted on Azure and has an IIS web server running.

Have 3 middlewares configured,

**server.js**

```
app.use(middlewares.ipcheck)
app.use('/:lang*', middlewares.redirection)
app.use(microcache.cacheSeconds(600, middlewares.microcache))
```

Based on the Azure logs, the code hits the `microcache` middleware and then goes back to the `ipcheck` middleware.

**ipcheck.js**

```
  if (req.query.skipGeo || req.cookies.geoCheck || isBot(req)) {
    console.log(`Cookie Present \n`)
    let hour = 3600000
    res.cookie('geoCheck', 'passed', { maxAge: 365 * 24 * hour })
    next()
  } else {
    console.log(`Checking against mmdb \n`)
    const isValidIP = await user.hasValidIp(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress)
    process.env.isValidIP = isValidIP
    if (!isValidIP) {
      console.log(`Geo Block \n`)
      res.status(307).sendFile(path.resolve('public/geo_block.html'))
    } else {
      console.log(`Success \n`)
      next()
    }
  }
```

**microcache.js**

```
return config.useMicroCache.get() && `${req.hostname}${req.originalUrl}` // useMicroCache is a bool val set based on env.
```

**redirection.js**

```
  const params = req.params
  let lang = params.lang
  const site = utils.user.currentSite(req)
  if (!req.originalUrl.includes('api')) {
    if (!validLanguage(site, lang)) {
      lang = req.cookies.lang && validLanguage(site, req.cookies.lang) ? req.cookies.lang : site.languages.default
      config.useMicroCache.set(false)
      res.redirect(301, `/${lang}${req.originalUrl}`)
      return
    } else if (lang !== req.cookies.lang) {
      config.useMicroCache.set(false)
    } else {
      config.useMicroCache.set(true)
    }

    if (!isLowerCase(req.path)) {
      let parsedUrl = url.parse(req.originalUrl)
      parsedUrl.pathname = parsedUrl.pathname.toLowerCase()
      res.redirect(301, url.format(parsedUrl))
      return
    }
  }

  next()
```

Comment: I rather doubt anyone here is going to be able to do anything but offer wild guesses without seeing relevant code/configuration.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry about that added the code.

Comment: Can you see in the Chrome debugger (network tab) exactly what URL it is getting redirected to?  Have you added logging in your redirection.js file to see exactly what URL you are receiving and what you are redirecting to?  It seems the next step is debugging to see what the URL is and then figuring out what code path is causing that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Guess I figured where the problem is, the `lowercase` portion of the redirection code tries to redirect to the lowercase encoded URL which fails. Should I decode the URL before redirecting?

Comment: `res.redirect(301, url)` will encode the URL for you so it should not be encoded yet - see [source code here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L888).  It would be nice if this was in the Express doc, but it doesn't appear to be so I looked at the actual code (huge advantage of open source).

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the link! that's really helpful. I'm not explicitly encoding the URL anywhere though. I guess it's the `urlEncoded` parser that comes with `bodyParser` that's doing this?

Comment: I just told you that you don't have to encode the URL for `res.redirect()`.  Did you mean you're not DECODING the url?

Comment: @jfriend00 The URL hits the middleware and it's already encoded, not doing anything there (which I'm guessing is the `urlEncoded` parser). To fix this, I've modified my `if` to `if (!isLowerCase(decodeURI(req.path)))`

Comment: FYI, there are several places where a slight coding error can send you into the redirect loop.  For example, if you're regularly setting an invalid `lang`, you will loop.  I'd personally look for a better way to write this that isn't as vulnerable to that type of issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 Great! Thanks for the input. Will work on refactoring this :)